# ¿Es normal mostrar notificaciones de preguntas nuevas si hay etiquetas ignoradas?

Tags: soporte

Es la primera vez que pregunto en meta, mi pregunta tal vez no sea todo lo completa que debería ser aquí, pero no quería quedarme con la duda.

Lo dicho, tengo un conjunto de etiquetas ignoradas, no conozco muchos lenguajes y frameworks, por lo tanto me interesa centrarme en ayudar en lo que sé.

El hecho de estar trabajando en mis cosas y mirar de vez en cuando el título de la pestaña de SO para ver si hay alguna pregunta u otra notificación me parece extremadamente cómodo (el número entre paréntesis), sólo de un vistazo sé si puedo echar una mano a alguien.

El problema es que, aun habiendo ignorado ciertas etiquetas, el contador de notificaciones sigue aumentando.

¿Es normal esto?

No puedo compartir la grabación de pantalla del "error", pero cualquier usuario puede comprobarlo por sí mismo.

### El título de SO mostrando notificaciones.

[image: Captura de pantalla del error en cuestión]

Comment: cualquier usuario.. que ignore etiquetas ;)... la verdad no se en que navegador aparecen los numeros.. en opera, no los veo... solo un puntito cuando hay cosas nuevas...

Comment: Ahora he añadido una captura, ¿qué te parece? Es incómodo porque entro a SO a ver qué cambios hay, pero al estar ocultas dichas etiquetas, al recargar las preguntas no hay nada nuevo donde contestar.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que ese filtro es solo visual en la pantalla principal.. las ves, pero sombreadas.. por lo tanto supongo que para esa cuenta no las toma en cuenta..

Comment: Cuando recargás la pagina de preguntas, por un segundo se puede ver las preguntas ignoradas. Luego desaparecen. Así que supongo que realmente es puramente visual el filtro de etiquetas ignoradas...